# Remove scrolling for text output in quarto

Tags: r, quarto

I'd like to get my text output in html (generated from Quarto using r) in a box without the horizontal scrolling. My yaml currently looks like this:

```
---
format:
  html:
    code-overflow: wrap
    smooth-scroll: false
    toc: true
    toc-depth: 4
---
```

For this part in a code chunk:

```
cat("Patent 1:", strat_imp$Title[1])
```

I get this result:

[image]

But what I actually want is the text without the scroll bar. I'm sure that's easy to do with a yaml setting, but I could not find the solution.

Thanks already!

Comment: Try this CSS command anywhere in your Quarto document <style>
.main-container {
  max-width: unset;
}
</style>